# Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRole(USER)'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to use spring security 5.3

configure on xml like this

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/list" access="hasRole(USER)"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/security" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <http-basic />
    <form-login login-page="/security"
                  login-processing-url="/security"
                  default-target-url="/list"
                  authentication-failure-url="/security?error"
                  username-parameter="username"
                  password-parameter="password"/>

    <logout logout-success-url="/security?logout"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="$2a$10$BHjEcnhAgqRH0Vj6aPmGTOtQfYdx3PsvTWjsVxVBouiLTzGSLTSz2" authorities="USER"/>
        </user-service>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

when I log in I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression
>   'hasRole(USER)'
>     org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:33)
>     org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
>     org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:155)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
>
> Root Cause
>
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   Property or field 'USER' cannot be found on object of type
>   'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
>   - maybe not public or not valid?  org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getArguments(MethodReference.java:164)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:94)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:302)
>     org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:33)
>     org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
>     org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:155)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)

what error in my code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I replaced `hasRole(USER)` with `hasAuthority('USER')` and it worked

Comment: Yes, because hasRole('USER') is the same as hasAuthority('ROLE_USER'). It's a small thing that most people stumble over.

Comment: Why did you post 2 answers to your question? Does this problem really have 4 solutions?

Comment: Should this not hit ant type error from the java compiler?

Comment: @delijati Should Java compiler evaluate String content?

Answer (score 2):

`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'USER' cannot be found on object of type`

From the error above you can see the problem is hte USER  that is not being recognized from the spring security framework. You have forgotten to add enclose the USER in '' .

The problem is with the expression: `<intercept-url pattern="/list" access="hasRole(USER)"/>`.
Replace it with  `<intercept-url pattern="/list" access="hasRole('USER')"/>` and it will work.

A another problem I saw it that you are using hasRole to protect your `/list` resource but you have given the user the authority USER `authorities="USER"`. What will  happen is that hasRole is going to add the prefix ROLE_ to USER argument you passed in. So ROLE_USER is not  going to equal USER which is the autority you have assign to the user.

To fix this you can either change authorities to ```authorities="ROLE_USER"``.

Or you can substitute hasRole with hasAuthority , like below:
`access="hasAuthority('USER')"`.

Comment: I did as you said, but I get an error: The server received the request, but refused to authorize it.

Comment: I think I found the problem why spring security refuses to authorize your request. It is because ``` access="hasRole(USER)"``` and assigned the user with authority USER ```authorities="USER"```. The hasRole checks the given authority but will add the prefix ROLE_. So what you can do is to replace ```authorities="USER"``` with ```authorities="ROLE_USER"``` and it will work.

Comment: Another way how to solve this problem is not to use hasRole, but to use hasAuthority. In these case you dont need to add the prefix ROLE_.   What you need to do in this case is to replace access="hasRole(USER)"``` with access="hasAuthority('USER')"```.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
hasRole('USER')
```

Note: the **single quotes** around USER.

Comment: I get an error: The server received the request, but refused to authorize it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I used the `@PreAuthorize` on the controller methods with multiple roles.
It was used as `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')")`

But the correct syntax should be `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`